# Graphics won't clear on a transparent JPanel

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, graphics2d

I am creating a blank transparent JPanel and then drawing lines to form boxes on it. I want to increase the size of the box but when I do I end up leaving a trail behind where the lines used to be.
I've done much searching online but can't seem to find a solution that works for me.
Any help would be much appreciated!

```
public class AVTBox extends JPanel {

private int boxSize = 100;
private boolean started = false, stopped = true, track = false;
private final int center = 150;
private final int maxBoxSize = 300, minBoxSize = 25;
private final int lockBoxSize = 30;

public AVTBox() 
{
    this.setOpaque(false);
    this.repaint();
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g.create();

    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3.0f));
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(center - (boxSize/2), center - (boxSize/2) + (boxSize*0.3), 
                              center - (boxSize/2), center + (boxSize/2) - (boxSize*0.3))
    );
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(center + (boxSize/2), center - (boxSize/2) + (boxSize*0.3), 
                              center + (boxSize/2), center + (boxSize/2) - (boxSize*0.3))
    );
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(center - (boxSize/2) + (boxSize*0.3), center - (boxSize/2), 
                              center + (boxSize/2) - (boxSize*0.3), center - (boxSize/2))
    );
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(center - (boxSize/2) + (boxSize*0.3), center + (boxSize/2), 
                              center + (boxSize/2) - (boxSize*0.3), center + (boxSize/2))
    );
    g2.dispose();
}

public void setBoxSize(String change)
{
    switch (change) {
        case "add":
            if(boxSize < maxBoxSize)
            {
                boxSize++;
            }   break;
        case "sub":
            if(boxSize > minBoxSize)
            {
                boxSize--;
            }   break;
    }
    this.revalidate();
    this.repaint();
}
}
```

**EDIT**: Everything works as it should when the panel has a full non-transparent background but moving these lines on a transparent background leaves painted parts behind. I need to find a way of getting this 'animation' working on a transparent background.

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJoiE.jpg) shows what should happen when the user increases the box size (green arrow) and what happens at the moment (red arrow).

Sorry for the terrible MSpaint image!

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). But `this.setLayout(null);` does not bode well..

Comment: Does this code have the problem?? I dont think soo You not gonna get help if you give us irrelevant code!!

Comment: Don't use setOpaque(false) in the paintComponent() method. The painting methods are for painting only and you should not be changing the properties of your component in the painting method. Set the property in the constructor.

Comment: @gpasch Yes this is the code with the problem. It works perfectly fine with a non-transparent background. It is when I try it on a transparent background that I get the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out; I was adding this JPanel to another JPanel instead of a JFrame. Not completely sure why but everything worked perfectly after being added directly to the JFrame.